# Are component tags always empty?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Regarding template parsing, [the documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Template-Parsing) says:

> Although in simple cases it might appear to work, you can not rely on
>   custom elements being expanded before browser validation. E.g.
>   `<my-select><option>...</option></my-select>` is not a valid template
>   even if `my-select` component eventually expands to
>   `<select>...</select>`.

That made me wonder: is there any case in which it is useful to have content between the opening and closing tags of a custom element? It seems to me that such content is thrown away. Maybe something in the [`beforeCompile`](http://vuejs.org/api/#beforeCompile) code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the contents in your component by using the `<slot>` element. See [the docs](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) for more information.

BTW, that warning only applies to Vue 1.0. In the upcoming 2.0 release, templates will be compiled outside of the DOM, so custom elements will always be expanded before browser validation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not thrown away. As Joseph said, you can insert it with `<slot>` You just have to make sure you don't create an invalid HTML structure.

You can use the `is` attribute to handle situations where you need to use an invalid HTML structure with a component.  This happens a lot with tables, you would use:

```
<table>
  <tr is="my-component">
```

Instead of

```
<table>
  <my-component>
```

To ensure your code is HTML compliant